# Spring batch improve performance by Partitioning

Tags: spring-batch

I need to convert the existing project to Spring batch job to make improvement the job's speed.
Suppose I have the first tasklet to retrive a list of data from database and put it to listener. So the next step can retrieve it from @BeforeStep and do some condition to get another list (10k-20k records) then proceed multiple business logic for each record.
But I am stuck how to implement this step by partition in Spring batch. I found all tutorials using directly query in reader and injected by the ExecutionContext in rangePartitioner. But I can't follow like that way.

```
<job id="testJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1"  next="step2">
        <tasklet ref="driver"/>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="promotionListener">
            </listener>
        </listeners>
    </step>
    <step id="step2"> 
      <tasklet >
        <chunk reader="bmtbBillGenReqReader"
            processor="bmtbBillGenReqProcessor"
            writer="bmtbBillGenReqWriter"
            commit-interval="1">                       
        </chunk>
      </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
<bean id="promotionListener"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
    <property name="keys">
        <util:list>
            <value>billGenRequests</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please advise how can I implement partition from **step2**. maybe store the new list from step2 to csv file or somethings first?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own partitionner instead of using RangePartitionner and retrieve the data in this implementation, instead of a dedicated step.
Then pass data for each partition to create according to your needs. For example

```
public class FilesPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> filesname = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
                "SELECT DISTINCT FILENAME FROM MYTABLE", String.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < filesname.size(); i++) {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
            executionContext.put("data", filesname.get(i));
            String key = filesname.get(i);
            map.put(key, executionContext);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

And inject the parameters accordingly in reader